# How to transfer csv files from Google Cloud Storage to Azure Datalake Store

Tags: azure, google-cloud-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I'd like to have our daily csv log files transferred from GCS to Azure Datalake Store, but I can't really figure out what would be the easiest way for it.
Is there a built-in solution for that?
Can I do that with Data Factory?
I'd rather avoid running a VM scheduled to do this with the apis. The idea comes from the GCS->(DataFlow->)BigQuery solution.
Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can move data from Google Cloud Storage to Azure Data lake Store using Azure Data Factory by developing custom copy activity. However, in this activity, you will be using APIs for transferring that data. See details on [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-use-custom-activities/) article.